# Create a monthly records tables from different scripts

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask for some idea support how to achieve to create a table from 5 different MYSQL scripts in PHP. The result of each of them is  SUM of data group by months.
I do not want to vast time much to scripts because all of them are ok when activates alone.

I will put theoretical query in order to not make my message very long.

```
<?php
$qry = "SUM(CASH) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());

$qry2 = "SUM(DEBT) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());

$qry3 = "SUM(DEBTPAID) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry3) or die(mysql_error());

$qry4 = "SUM(INVOICE) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry4) or die(mysql_error());

$qry5 = "SUM(NVOICEPAYOFF) group by MONTH DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry5) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I want to achieve a TABLE like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>CASH</td>
  <td>DEBT</td>
  <td>DEBTPAID</td>
  <td>INVOICE</td>
  <td>INVOICEPAYOFF</td>
</tr>
<?
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td><label>'. $row['CASH'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row2['DEBT'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row3['DEBTPAID'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row4['INVOICE'] .'</label></td>';
echo '<td><label>'. $row5['INVOICEPAYOFF'] .'</label></td>';
echo '</tr>';

?>
</table>
```

I will appreciete your every idea, solutions or recommendation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Really a SQL question.  Look how to write a single SQL query to get your full desired result.  Either using joins/selecting multiple columns, or sub selects.  Then the rest should fall into place.

Comment: Are all these queries count sum in the same table?

Comment: Each QUERY is JOINT TABLES... nothing in common to each other - only time is something common... to join all 5 queries in one might be like a JOINof  more then 20 colums from more then 10 tables together... the solutsion should be other

Comment: Tables are totally diferent - only DATETIME might be a common if to GROUP BY MONTH

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
SELECT sum(cash) as 'cash', sum(debt) as 'debt',
  sum(debtpaid) as 'debtpaid', sum(invoice) as 'invoice',
  sum(invoicepaid) as 'invoicepaid'
FROM my_table
GROUP BY MONTH DESC
```

Comment: It is not so simple... Every query is a multimple JOINT tables... I can not do like this...

Comment: Then post an example where we can actually answer your question.